# How to avoid the application stalling when loading a large widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder, dart-isolates

I need to load a huge widget (built after a very wide number of loops) on a screen during (or before) the page load that will contain it. I managed to do it, but the process froze the whole application until its end. My goal is to show a spinning progress indicator until the widget is loaded without freezing the application.

I've tried Future building, Future functions, and/or Isolates, but the result has always been the same.

One of the attempts, for example, was:

```
Widget buildHugeWidget(int value) {
  … a lot of loops …
  return theHugeWidget;
}

class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  …
 @override
 State<Screen> createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {

  Widget? hugeWidget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    validateAccess(context).then((value) => super.initState()
    ).whenComplete(() => {
      WidgetsBinding.instance
          .addPostFrameCallback((_) => buildCompute())
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: 
        ....
        Container(
            ...
            child:
            hugeWidget!= null
            ? hugeWidget
            : const Center(
              child: SizedBox(height: 40, width: 40, child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            )
        ),
        ...
    );   
  }

  void buildCompute() {
    compute(buildHugeWidget, 1).then((hwLocal) => {
      setState(() => hugeWidget = hwLocal)
    });
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would strongly suggest trying Futures again. I still find them tough after building many widgets with them. Keep at it and try building small widgets first with them.

Comment: @returnVoid with small widgets, or few loops, all works as expected. Unfortunately, increasing the number of loops the side effect is more effective to each step.

Comment: Are you calling compute multiple times quickly ? Because no matter how intensive the isolate task is it won't block the main thread. I would suggest that the isolate function that is passed to `compute` return something that is not a widget but what you need to use in a widget. Also as suggested by @returnVoid try using FutureBuilders and completers if needed.

Comment: @Calvin Gonsalves, no I think, I'm trying to limit accesses by putting the call into the initState method, through the addPostFrameCallback syntax. The multiple operations should be only in the function called by compute. Unfortunately, the wide loops are used to build the widget components (that are widgets themselves), so a widget is the only type that I can return. The freezing may be caused by the heavy widget construction, as the problem is resolved by replacing it with a simple Future.delayed(Duration (seconds: 10)). Completers could be another attempt, I will try. Thanks